# How can I let a user navigate and play a playlist using the HTML5 <audio> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-audio

I want to link a playlist with the `<audio>` element in HTML5, so that:

- When one song in the list ends, the next song starts automatically
- The user can switch to the next or previous song in the playlist

How can this be achieved through HTML5, JavaScript etc.? I'm using ASP.NET at the backend.

Also, can I give user the liberty to play any song from his/her playlist alongside the audio player?
My friend told me that it can be achieved by tweaking its DOM (Document Object Model). Please help how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about jQuery HTML5 Audio Player? http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02/